# Wait for pool.apply_async inside a loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement multiprocessing in my python code for the first time. I am stuck, since I cannot make async_apply wait for all its processes to finish. I'd like to process the elements in smaller chunks and save the results while I go through the long list of elements.

As a simpler example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun(x, y):
    print("here")
    return(x+y)

buffer = []

for val in range(10):
    buffer.append(val)
    print(f{Added value: {val})
    if len(buffer) == 5:
        #It is my understanding, this is necessary on Windows
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            pool = mp.Pool()
            res = [pool.apply_async(fun, args = (x,x)) for x in buffer]
            res = [r.wait() for r in res]
            print(f'Results: {res}')
            buffer = []
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

I would love this to produce the following output:

```
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Results: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Results: [10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

*But* it actually produces this (on my machine, at least):

```
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Results: [None, None, None, None, None]
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Added value: 0
Added value: 1
Added value: 2
Added value: 3
Added value: 4
Added value: 5
Added value: 6
Added value: 7
Added value: 8
Added value: 9
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Results: [None, None, None, None, None]
```

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Try `Pool.map` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map

Comment: If I use map the situation gets better (it actually outputs results), but the loop still runs in the background and provides a lot of extra-output -- much like in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the whole for loop *in* the conditional suite.

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for val in range(10):
        buffer.append(val)
        print(f'Added value: {val}')
        if len(buffer) == 5:
            pool = mp.Pool()
            res = [pool.apply_async(fun, args = (x,x)) for x in buffer]
            # wait til they are ALL done ?
            for r in res:
                r.wait()
            # get the return values
            res = [r.get() for r in res]
            print(f'Results: {res}')
            buffer = []
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

---

Here is your original with some extra inspection. I still don't know why but it appears that somehow the lines in the for loop are running in multiple python processes.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pickle

def fun(x, y, pid=None):
    print(f"here pid:{pid}",file=sys.stderr)
    return (x+y,pid)

buffer = []
stuff = []

with open(r'c:\pyProjects\stuff.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(stuff,f)

for val in range(10):
    buffer.append(val)
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f'Added value: {val}.   pid={pid}')
    d = {'val':val,'pid':pid}
    with open(r'c:\pyProjects\stuff.pkl','rb') as f:
        try:
            stuff = pickle.load(f)
            stuff.append(d)
        except EOFError as e:
            s = '\n'.join(f'\t\t\t\t{item}' for item in stuff)
            print(f'\t\t\tEOFError {d}\n\t\t\tstuff:\n{s}\n')
    with open(r'c:\pyProjects\stuff.pkl','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(stuff,f)
    if len(buffer) == 5:
        print(buffer)
        #It is my understanding, this is necessary on Windows
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            pool = mp.Pool()
            res = [pool.apply_async(fun, args = (x,x,pid)) for x in buffer]
            res = [r.get() for r in res]
            print(f'\t\t\tResults: {res}')
            buffer = []
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

After it finishes you can load and peruse the pickled file with

```
>>> import pickle
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> with open(r'c:\pyProjects\stuff.pkl','rb') as f:
...     a = pickle.load(f)

>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: x['pid'])
>>> pprint(a)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Would you be able to provide or point to an explanation of what is happening? I am really confused...however, thank you again.

Comment: @non87 - I do not know why your original behaves that way - there are only two results printed out and the values are correct (if you change to `res = [r.get() for r in res]`) - it is kinda like all that extra stuff are print *echoes*. I imagine a little introspection might help figure it out. To be candid, your code *structure* looked funny so I just tried it the way I thought it should be and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! Once I have the code up and running I will actually look at the pickle file. As I mentioned, this is my very first use of the mp library, so I don't really understand much of what is going on -- and my implementation can indeed be funny